# How to use wkhtmltopdf without install it to the server

Tags: web-services, installation, web-hosting, wkhtmltopdf, shared-hosting

I'm using a free web hosting solution (000freehosting.com) that doesn't allow me to install any new tools, so I'm wondering if I could use `wkhtmltopdf` without installing it on the server.

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: Good Question bro. Tell me if you have find the way for this thing

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires installation from the admin. You'll need to use something like DomPDF that doesn't have any dependencies and can be added as a folder to your web directory.